Why can't I install more than one version of php with the ondrej ppa?
I ran
docker run -it ubuntu:22.04 bash 


apt install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt update
apt install php8.2 -y

but I get the error Unable to locate package php8.2. Same error for any other version other than php8.1.
apt list php also shows only php packages related 8.1. I thought the ondrej ppa was supposed to hold multiple versions of php. How do I access other versions please?

I have the same problem with new vps ubuntu , I can't install php8.2 nor  php8.3. Did you found a solution ?

No. Better just to use Docker. https://hub.docker.com/_/php
